# fail to set java environment variables on mac

Tags: java, macos, environment-variables

I got a weird problem when I try to set java environment variables on my mac. Here is what I did:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

edit:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

save then

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

check

```
echo $JAVA_HOME

/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

So far everything is good. But my problem is that when I reboot, **echo $JAVA_HOME** shows nothing. 
After typing **source ~/.bashrc** again, **echo $JAVA_HOME** shows the correct result which means I need to type **source ~/.bashrc** every time when I reboot mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on OSX by default `.bash_profile` is used, not `.bashrc`

Comment: It works! Thanks. I am wondering why some tutorials use .bashrc on OSX, which should be .bash_profile.